# CSS empty definition necessary to have the type as specificity selector (material UI in React)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, jss

The styling for the unselected toggle button works nicely.

But the style of the selected toggle button does not appear when you don't define an empty class selector:

**./App.js**

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import { createStyles, WithStyles } from "@material-ui/core";
import { ToggleButtonGroup, ToggleButton } from "@material-ui/lab";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const styles = () =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      backgroundColor: "blue",
      "&$selected": {
        color: "blue",
        backgroundColor: "yellow"
      }
    },
    // this empty definition needs to be here otherwise it won't work
    selected: {}
  });

export interface IAppProps extends WithStyles<typeof styles> {}

const App: React.FC<IAppProps> = ({ classes }: IAppProps) => {
  return (
        <ToggleButton
          classes={{
            root: classes.root,
            selected: classes.selected
          }}
          selected={true}
        >
          option 1
        </ToggleButton>
  );
};

const AppWithStyles = withStyles(styles)(App);
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<AppWithStyles />, rootElement);
```

This *perhaps* has something to do with the type definition in the props. When you remove the selector 'selected' from the *styles* definition, it is not available anymore in the interface IAppProps.

How can you define this type in the interface?

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-sammet-y7wh7?fontsize=14

---

update 1: Also tried *Augmenting the props* as described [in the material-ui docs](https://material-ui.com/guides/typescript/#augmenting-your-props-using-withstyles):

```js
const styles = () =>
  createStyles({
    toggleButton: {
      backgroundColor: "blue",
      "&$toggleButtonSelected": {
        color: "blue",
        backgroundColor: "yellow"
      }
    },
  });

export interface IAppProps {
  classes: {
    toggleButton: string;
    toggleButtonSelected: string;
  };
}

const App: React.FC<IAppProps> = ({ classes }: IAppProps) => {
// ...
```

With no luck.

---

update 2: using a hook makes the type casting redundant, but it also won't fix this:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import { createStyles, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";
import { ToggleButtonGroup, ToggleButton } from "@material-ui/lab";

const useStyles = makeStyles(() =>
    createStyles({
      root: {
        backgroundColor: "blue",
        "&$selected": {
          color: "blue",
          backgroundColor: "red"
        }
      },
      // this still needs to be there...
      // selected: {}
    })
  )

export interface IAppProps {}

const App: React.FC<IAppProps> = () => {

  const classes = useStyles();

  return ( 
    // ...
  )
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you just have a misunderstanding of how JSS works and the meaning of some of the syntax. The relevant documentation is [here](https://cssinjs.org/jss-plugin-nested/?v=v10.0.0-alpha.10#use-rulename-to-reference-a-local-rule-within-the-same-style-sheet).

When you define your styles object (or function taking in the theme and returning an object), each key in that object is referred to by JSS as a "rule". The key is the rule name and JSS will translate the value into a CSS class. The `classes` object that you get back from `useStyles` or that gets injected as a prop when using `withStyles` then maps the rule names to the generated CSS class names.

The `$ruleName` syntax is a way to refer to the CSS class name of one of the other rules in your styles object. The `&` refers to the parent rule. In your example you have rules called `root` and `selected` (when it isn't commented out).

The following:

```
root: {
        backgroundColor: "blue",
        "&$selected": {
          color: "blue",
          backgroundColor: "red"
        }
      },
selected: {}
```

would compile to CSS like the following:

```
.root-0 {
   background-color: blue;
}
.root-0.selected-0 {
   color: blue;
   background-color: red;
}
```

By passing the following to Material-UI:

```
          classes={{
            root: classes.root,
            selected: classes.selected
          }}
          selected={true}
```

You are telling it to apply "root-0 selected-0" as class names in addition to the class names applied for the default styling. Without the empty `selected: {}` rule name, you can't refer to `$selected` from the `root` rule (JSS should be giving you a warning in the console if you do).

There is a slightly simpler alternative (as of v4) for referring to the `selected` class name. `selected` is one of the Material-UI special states that it refers to as [pseudo-classes](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#pseudo-classes) and the documentation provides the default class name for each (e.g. `Mui-selected`).

This means you can do the following:

```
root: {
        backgroundColor: "blue",
        "&.Mui-selected": {
          color: "blue",
          backgroundColor: "red"
        }
      }
```

This is no longer referencing another rule, so `selected: {}` isn't needed and neither is `selected: classes.selected` needed in the `classes` prop. Instead this is referencing the actual class name that Material-UI applies for the default styling when `selected={true}`.